# How to read local xml file using $.ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax, firefox-addon

I am trying to build a Firefox extension for which I need to read local xml file but does not able to read file using `$.ajax`. My code is like below:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "file:///C:/Users/Mitul Gandhi/Desktop/Library_en.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) { }
});
```

Comment: If it's a FF extension, why do you use Ajax and not FF's file IO? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/File_I_O.

Answer (score 4):

Due to security reasons javascript ajax calls cannot read local file contents.

To read a local file in a Firefox addon you can use `Components` (file IO) like so:

```
function Read(file)
{
    var ioService=Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"]
        .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService);
    var scriptableStream=Components
        .classes["@mozilla.org/scriptableinputstream;1"]
        .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIScriptableInputStream);

    var channel=ioService.newChannel(file,null,null);
    var input=channel.open();
    scriptableStream.init(input);
    var str=scriptableStream.read(input.available());
    scriptableStream.close();
    input.close();
    return str;
}

var contents = Read("C:/Users/Mitul Gandhi/Desktop/Library_en.xml");
```